# Add custom marker to Here static map api

Tags: here-api

Hello is there a way to add a custom marker to the https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map-image/map-image-address API end point? Also is there a way to improve the quality of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add custom marker to the end of the mentioned Rest Map Image API however you can try the alternative API for javascript to achieve your goal.

In order to add the marker you have to convert the address into coordinates.

below is the example of javascript which can help you.

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/servicesRouting/geocode-a-location-from-structured-address

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/servicesRouting/geocode-a-location-from-address

I hope this will help.

Comment: OK great thank you so much for this information.  With that is there anyway to improve the quality of the image?

Comment: You can specify the PPI when creating a default layer with javascript as:
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(512, 320);
Also in Rest API you can append the ppi(pixel per inch) parameter in the end for the resolution.Resolution that can be requested, valid values are: 72 – normal, used by default if no value provided 250 – mobile 320 – hi-res